# How to pass data from app.component.ts to other page in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have published and event with some json data in login page and subscribed that event in app.component.ts and I consoled it and it shows the json data in console output and now I want to pass the subscribed event data (json data) to another page in side menu, where it uses the open(page) method in app.component.ts

### login.ts

```
this.events.publish('user:login', this.afterLoginObject);
```

### app.component.ts

```
events.subscribe('user:login', (afterLoginObject) => {
  this.componentJSON = afterLoginObject;
  console.log(this.componentJSON);
});

openPage(page) {
this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
```

}

here I got stuck... I want to send the subscribed json object to other pages along with the page navigation from side menu method openPage(). so that I can use the same json through out the application globally.
any answers please thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you subscribe agin in the new component for the same observable

Comment: Please show us your code and where you are facing issue.

Comment: @RahulSingh i tried but its not working...

Comment: Please edit your question and add as code block, so it is readable :)

Comment: @AJT_82 please check the post again ...

Comment: Did you read Rahul's comment? That is a good option in my opinion.

Comment: @AJT_82 i tried... soon i click the login button.. i subscribed the same published event in dashboard page and app.component.ts but it consoles the app.componnet.ts and its not consolling in dashboard page. so i need to know the one publish multiple subscription.. I dont know how to achieve it

Comment: Where are you trying to subscribe exactly in the component? `Events` should emit every time there is a subscriber.

Comment: @AJT_82 I have subscribed the event is app.component.ts constructor and I'm trying to pass the data to side menu so that when ever the page is selected from the side menu ... the information flows equally... i think so... i know i'm going in wrong way... please guide me

Comment: For some reason I have some problem understanding the issue here :D If you subscribe to `Events` it will emit the last value. Please create a demo showcasing the issue for better understanding. You can make a StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-3asaw7

Comment: @AJT_82 dude... my problem is... i have subscribed the json data from login page and i want to send the data while navigating to page from sidemenu so that each page uses the same data ..

Comment: Then why not subscribe to that event on each page, like you have in the login page?

Comment: @AJT_82 i try to do it.. but its not working dude... and i don't know how to do multiple subscriptions for one published events...

Comment: Well, you just subscribe like you have in app component: `events.subscribe('user:login', (afterLoginObject) => {
  // do stuff
});`

Answer (score 1):

**Either you can use a shared service for this or you can pass data between the components using event emitter,@input,@output,@viewchild if they follow parent-child relationship .**

Please refer the below link :

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Answer (score 0):

You can send data to specific page like below.

```
openPage(page) {

this.nav.setRoot(page.component, {'componentJSON' : this.componentJSON });
}
```

You can grab `componentJSON` in another page using `NavParams` like below.

```
constructor(private nav : NavParams) {

    let data = this.nav.get('componentJSON');
}
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-a3patc?file=pages%2Fcontact%2Fcontact.ts)

If you want to use `componentJSON` globally inside your app you have to use `Data Service.`  [this link](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/) will be helpful to implement `Data Service.`